# How to make an asynchronous call using Spring5 WebClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I am new to Spring Reactive framework & trying to make an asynchronous call using Spring5 WebClient.
I was able to do the same call as synchronous successfully. But facing issue with asynchronous call.

I am using the below code to make an asynchronous call :

```
Mono<ClientResponse> reponse = WebClient.builder().build().post()
.uri("http://api.com")
.body(BodyInserters.fromObject("data"))
.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
.header("Authorization", "Bearer blahblahblahblah")
.exchange();

// couple of logger messages and other statements
```

The problem is it is not executing the API call and not giving the response. It is continuing with other statements execution but it never calls API call.

I do not want to use `block()` method as it will convert it into sync call.

I have searched for so many websites and documentation but the same code is using for asynchronous calls. But not sure why it is not working. Can anyone help me if I miss anything?

Comment: if this is a webflux application, you should probably not subscribe. The one that initiates the call is the subscriber. So if there is a calling client, then that calling client should be the one subscribing. Please post your full code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77391267/2462531 It's worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the result. This can be done with a [`block()` call](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#block--):

> Subscribe to this Mono and block indefinitely until a next signal is received. Returns that value, or null if the Mono completes empty. In case the Mono errors, the original exception is thrown (wrapped in a RuntimeException if it was a checked exception).

Without the subscription, the call is not executed by design. You can, however, pass the prepared mono in other stream to combine them, but to get the result you have to call a termination operation somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but as I mentioned in question I don't wat to use block() as it goes as synchronous call. Any other possibilities for asynchronous calls?

Comment: [`subscribe`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#subscribe--) + onComplete. Or just [`toFuture`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#toFuture--)

Comment: I am using subscribe() as suggested in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50223891/how-to-extract-response-header-status-code-from-spring-5-webclient-clientrespo. How can I use onComplete along with subscribe ?

Comment: im downvoting this answer since it hasn't been established yet who the subscriber should be. Is his application the client or is there any other client that is the actual subscriber. This answer is not a correct answer until this information has been established.

Answer (score 0):

Below code could work.

```
Mono<ClientResponse> reponse =
WebClient.builder().build().post()
.uri("http://api.com")
.body(BodyInserters.fromObject("data"))
.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
.header("Authorization", "Bearer blahblahblahblah")
.bodyToMono(ClientResponse.class)
.retrieve();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use subscribe () function to make a asynchronous call. Hope it works..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use below code, it resolved your problem.

```
String response = WebClient.builder().build()
                    .post()
                    .uri("http://api.com")
                    .header("Authorization", "Bearer yourtoken")
                    .body(Mono.just(body), BodyClassName.class)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(String.class).block();
```