# Get status code of Spring WebClient request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webclient

My goal is to get the HttpStatus from a Spring WebClient request. All other information of the request is irrelevant.

My old way of doing this was:

```
WebClient.builder().baseUrl("url").build()
        .get().exchange().map(ClientResponse::statusCode).block();
```

With Spring Boot 2.4.x/Spring 5.3, the `exchange` method of WebClient is deprecated in favor of `retrieve`.

With the help of https://stackoverflow.com/a/65791800 i managed to create the following solution.

```
WebClient.builder().baseUrl("url").build()
        .get().retrieve()
        .toEntity(String.class)
        .flatMap(entity -> Mono.just(entity.getStatusCode()))
        .block();
```

However, this looks like a very "hacky" way and and does not work when 4xx or 5xx responses are received (In this case the result is null).

Comment: Why are you blocking on a reactive call? Just use `RestTemplate` if you’re blocking anyway.

Comment: See also https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.ResponseSpec.html#toBodilessEntity--

Comment: Finally https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec.html#exchangeToMono-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: @BoristheSpider Because `RestTemplate` is getting deprecated: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html I prefer not to use functionality that may not be usable in the foreseeable future.

Comment: where do you see that in the link you posted?

Comment: In the class comment @BoristheSpider
> NOTE: As of 5.0 this class is in maintenance mode, with only minor requests for changes and bugs to be accepted going forward. Please, consider using the org.springframework.web.reactive.client.WebClient which has a more modern API and supports sync, async, and streaming scenarios.

Comment: Maintenance mode is **not** deprecation. You’re reading between lines that don’t exist. If you have legacy blocking code use the legacy blocking api.

Comment: I agree with you on this point, however to stay consistent within the application I would like to use the WebClient. However, this function should no longer block and use the asynchronous functionality. Task for this is created :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can be solved with the method `exchangeToMono`. This results into the following snippet.

```
WebClient.builder().baseUrl("url").build()
        .get().exchangeToMono(response -> Mono.just(response.statusCode()))
        .block();
```

The usage of the `retrieve` method can be improved in the following way, still not very clean.

```
WebClient.builder().baseUrl("url").build()
        .get().retrieve()
        .onStatus(httpStatus -> true, clientResponse -> {
            //Set variable to return here
            status.set(clientResponse.statusCode());
            return null;
        })
        .toBodilessEntity().block();
```

Comment: as an additional comment, `exchangeToMono` is one of the 2 new methods introduced when `exchange` was deprecated to allow the same functionality as before without the dangers of memory leaks. This is stated on their javadoc
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec.html#exchange