# How to use Spring Security with load balancer?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, load-balancing, spring-cloud

I am new at loadBalancing so please I need help and thats what i did :
i built 2 services as 2 apps (A,B) I used spring security on both of them
(both of them are restfull api , they have theymleaf and full frontEnd pages ),
then i had made another app as spring cloud loadbalancer .
when i send a request , it go from loadbalancer app to one of the 2 services but the problem is  when iam not authenticated the response will be empty , it wont take me to the default login page as usual as when i use the normal A app directly , and when i go to pages that does not need to be authenticated to get to it , it is returned without my css/js styles

this is my A app controller ( it is returning view not json )

```java
    package com.hariri_stocks.controllers;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    import com.hariri_stocks.models.Estates;
    import com.hariri_stocks.models.SoldEstates;
    import com.hariri_stocks.models.Users;
    import com.hariri_stocks.services.estatesService;

    @Controller
    public class LoginController {

        @Autowired
        estatesService ES;
        
        
        @GetMapping(value = "/")
        public String login() {
            return "/signIn-up.html";
        }
        
        @GetMapping(value = "/dashboard")
        public String dashboard(Model model ,@RequestParam(required = false) String add_result
                                                    ,@RequestParam(required = false) String alert_err) {
            List<Estates> estates = ES.findAll();
            model.addAttribute("estates",estates);

        return "/dashboard";
        }
        
        @GetMapping(value = "/dashboard/unSold")
        public String unselled_stocks(Model model) {
            List<Estates> estates = ES.findUnsold();

            if(estates.size() > 0) 
            model.addAttribute("estates",estates);
            
            else
            model.addAttribute("error","there is no sold estates yet !!");
            return "/dashboard";
        }
        
        @Value(value = "${server.port}")
        String port_num;
        
        @GetMapping("/port")
        public String hello() {
            return port_num;
        }
        
    }
```

and this is my loadbalancer controller iam using @restcontroller

```java
    package com.hariri_loadbalancer;

    import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.ReactorLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

    @SpringBootApplication
    @RestController
    public class UserApplication {

      private final WebClient.Builder loadBalancedWebClientBuilder;
      private final ReactorLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction lbFunction;

      public UserApplication(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder,
          ReactorLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction lbFunction) {
        this.loadBalancedWebClientBuilder = webClientBuilder;
        this.lbFunction = lbFunction;
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserApplication.class, args);
      }

      @RequestMapping("/port")
      public Mono<String> showMePort() {
        return loadBalancedWebClientBuilder.build().get().uri("http://hariri/port")
            .retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
      }
      @RequestMapping("/")
      public Mono<String> showMainPage() {
        return loadBalancedWebClientBuilder.build().get().uri("http://hariri/")
            .retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
      }
    }
```

So what should I do? I feel that what I am doing is stupid,
should I move all my Thymleaf pages to the loadbalancer maybe , so that the a app return what it want to return with @restController then the loadbalancer use @controller to get to the styling front pages or there is a way , and for the security , should i implement the spring security with the loadbalancer instead of the A,B apps
.........................
8080 is loadBalancer port
9091 is A app port
so it seams that when A is returning the html page , the html is searching for the css at the loadbalancer machin at 8080 , while they are existing at A app on 9091

[image]

Comment: Please do both an accepted and rejected request to LoginController using verbose curl or postman and paste the complete response (including headers). Also do the same going through the loadbalancer. Im sure you will notice something different.

Answer (score 0):

bodyToMono decodes the body but you are not handling headers.
On spring security there is very likely a redirection to the login page ... so it wont work if you only attend to the body. This might be also affecting styles somehow.

Check something like this:
[How to extract response header & status code from Spring 5 WebClient ClientResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50223891/how-to-extract-response-header-status-code-from-spring-5-webclient-clientrespo)

Comment: for styles , it is searching for them on loadbalance app , while they are at the app A ...

Comment: @muhammad I see thats also a configuration problem likely. Anyway IMO you SHOULD NOT move your stylesheets to the LB.  Thats mixing concerns. You could place them in some CDN-like with very long TTL cache, so they are reachable and performant.